# Не сохраняются данные sqlite в docker volume

Tags: sqlite, docker, docker-compose

В моем проекте есть папка **db** и в нем храниться файл **mydb.sqlite**.

Вот мой файл **docker-compose**:

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
    todo-sqlite-data:
services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    volumes:
    - todo-sqlite-data:/db
```

Когда я останавливаю контейнер через **docker-compose down**, то через **docker volume ls** я вижу, что мой том еще существует. Но после запуска **docker-compose up** изменений **sqlite** не видно.

Если я указал **volume** данные же должны сохраняться. Может я указал путь **volume** в **docker-compose** не правильно?

Comment: Судя по этому примеру [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/nouchka/docker-sqlite3/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) должно быть todo-sqlite-data:/root/db/

Comment: Так должно сработать, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: Я заметил, что каждый раз при разворачивании (docker compose up) у меня создается новый volume. В таком случае старый volume не используется и данные поэтому теряются?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если при подключении не указать конкретную БД, то sqlite работает с временной БД в памяти, которая удаляется после окончания сессии.
Из документации [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html):

> Start the sqlite3 program by typing "sqlite3" at the command prompt, optionally followed by the name the file that holds the SQLite database (or ZIP archive). If the named file does not exist, a new database file with the given name will be created automatically. If no database file is specified on the command-line, a temporary database is created and automatically deleted when the "sqlite3" program exits.

Если открыть логи запущенного контейнера в Docker Desktop или выполнить команду вида

```
docker logs temp-sqlite3-1
```

там написано следующее:

> Connected to a transient in-memory database. Use ".open FILENAME" to
> reopen on a persistent database.

Соответственно, нужно создать постоянную БД, чтобы она сохранялась в volume.

Пример тестирования, при котором данные сохраняются:

1. развернуть контейнер

   ```
   docker-compose up -d
   ```
2. подключиться к контейнеру

   ```
   docker exec -it temp-sqlite3-1 bash
   ```
3. подключиться к БД

   ```
   sqlite3 test.db
   ```
4. создать таблицу и проверить, что она создана успешно

   ```
   create table test_table(id int, description varchar(10));  
   .tables
   ```
5. пересоздать контейнер

   ```
   docker-compose down  
   docker-compose up -d
   ```
6. выполнить пункты 2 и 3 и проверить, что таблица существует.

Если проверить список файлов через команду **ls** в папке root/db после подключения к контейнеру, то там будет файл test.db. К нему можно подключиться через команду **.open test.db** после подключения к sqlite.

Если же нужно примонтировать определенную папку из проекта, то используйте такой вариант:

```
services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./db:/root/db/
```

Объявление секции volumes в этом случае уже не нужно, монтируется папка с хост-машины к папке внутри контейнера (bind mounts). Подробнее можно прочитать тут [Manage data in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/).

Comment: У меня есть еще один service - app и в нем я запускаю проект телеграм бота. В этой программе я соединяюсь к базе sqlite с помощью пути ..с:/mr/tg/tg/db/reminder.db, и там же создаю таблицы. Возможно я не вижу изменений из за того что я подключаюсь в локальную reminderd.db, а не тому который у меня в volume сохранился? Может мне стоит найти путь к volume и подключиться там к созданному reminderd.db?

Comment: Думаю, для этого варианта как раз подходит bind mounts, только указывать уже не относительный, а абсолютный путь, например с:/mr/tg/tg/db/:/root/db/

Comment: Простите просто я новенький, а как это будет выглядеть в docker compose?

Comment: Для подключения к локальной БД reminder.db, которая хранится на вашем ПК например в папке с:/mr/tg/tg/db, нужно в секцию volumes добавить значение с:/mr/tg/tg/db/:/root/db/ В этом значении путь с:/mr/tg/tg/db/ - на хост-машине (Вашем ПК), путь /root/db/- внутри контейнера.

Comment: Примечание: желательно использовать относительные пути, а не абсолютные.

Comment: Связанный вопрос по обмену данными между контейнерами: [Ошибка docker: bind source path does not exist](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1377503/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-docker-bind-source-path-does-not-exist)

Comment: У меня программа сама создает изменения в бд. Как сделать по вашему только чтобы было автоматизировано?

Comment: Насколько понимаю, нужно изменить строку подключения в приложении. Предлагаю продолжить дальнейшее обсуждение в вопрос по ссылке выше для удобства.