# Ошибка docker: bind source path does not exist

Tags: sqlite, docker, docker-compose

Я пытаюсь сохранить данные **sqlite** вот мой **docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
    todo-sqlit-data:
services:
  app:
    build: ./tgreminder
    environment:
    - IDENTIFICATOR=2125884152
    
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: todo-sqlit-data
        target: /root/db/
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./tgreminder/tgreminder/db
        target: /opt/db/
    tty: true
```

После вывода команды **docker-compose up -d**, у меня выдает эту ошибку: *Cannot create container for service sqlite: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist..*
У меня **docker tools под 8й windows**, предполагаю в этом проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подобный вариант, чтобы обращаться к одному и тому же volume из разных контейнеров:

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
    todo-sqlite-data:

services:
  app:
    build: ./tgreminder
    environment:
      - IDENTIFICATOR=2125884152
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - todo-sqlite-data:/my/sqlite/path/

  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - todo-sqlite-data:/root/db/
```

Пример взят отсюда [How to connect Flask app to SQLite DB running in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811608/how-to-connect-flask-app-to-sqlite-db-running-in-docker) По этой же ссылке приведен пример строки подключения для python. При таком варианте относительный путь к БД указывать не нужно.

Comment: mr-reminder(dockercompose.yml тут)/tgreminder/tgreminder/db/reminderd.db - путь к базе

Comment: Предлагаю попробовать вариант с docker-compose без относительных путей к БД из ответа выше. Относительный путь к БД вы указали верно.

Comment: А можете пожалуйста показать как это сделать с абсолютными путями. Я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: `
  app:
    build: ./tgreminder
    environment:
    - IDENTIFICATOR=AAFXfwQtBhfK0
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./tgreminder/tgreminder/:/app
      - ./tgreminder/tgreminder/db/:/root/db/
    command: pipenv run gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --reload app:app
    
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:

      - ./tgreminder/tgreminder/db/:/root/db/
` The application tgreminder.dll does not exist. exited with code 145

Comment: Обновил пример в ответе. Попробуйте его, только надо перепроверить пути и изменить строку подключения в приложении так, чтобы она ссылалась на volume из docker-compose.

Comment: Все сделал. А есть какой нибудь способ сделать ссылку на volume в строке подключения?

Comment: А на каком языке программирования у вас приложение? Пример для python приведен по ссылке из ответа.

Comment: c#. Вот строка подключения `SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($@"Data Source=c:\users\Румиль\source\mr-reminder\tgreminder\tgreminder\db\reminderd.db");`

Comment: Смотрите, ваш volume - это путь внутри вашего контейнера к папке извне контейнера. Если вы укажете путь к папке напрямую, к примеру, C:/temp/:/root/db/ - это будет означать, что внутри контейнера по пути root/db будет доступно содержимое внешней папки C:/temp/. Все изменения, которые будут внесены в контейнере, будут видны вне контейнера и наоборот. Теперь возьмем созданный volume todo-sqlite-data. Это тоже папка, только уже не мы задаем к ней путь, а сам docker. И мы хотим, чтобы доступ к этой папке внутри контейнера был по пути root/db. Так мы и указали в нашем docker-compose.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134010/discussion-between-alexsteeel-and-maxssss).